# Can we overload main() function in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading, program-entry-point, standards

Since C+++ allows function overloading, can we overload `main()`?

For example,

```
int main(const std::string &)
{
   return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return main("calling overloaded main");
}
```

`gcc-4.3.4` doesn't compile this, and gives these errors: (see at [ideone](http://ideone.com/73cpy))

> prog.cpp:4: error: first argument of ‘int main(const std::string&)’ should be ‘int’
>   prog.cpp:4: error: ‘int main(const std::string&)’ takes only zero or two arguments
>   prog.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
>   prog.cpp:8: error: declaration of C function ‘int main(int, char**)’ conflicts with
>   prog.cpp:4: error: previous declaration ‘int main(const std::string&)’ here
>   prog.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
>   prog.cpp:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’
>   prog.cpp:8: error: too few arguments to function ‘int main(int, char**)’
>   prog.cpp:10: error: at this point in file

So I'm wondering if the C++ Standard *explicitly* forbids overloading of `main`? If so, which statement?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes it explicitly forbids that. Refer to 3.6.1p2

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded.

---

This way, the main function's name can stay unmangled. That is, the runtime library can call a symbol having a fixed name (e.g `main` or `_main`) to jump to the main function. The libraries' code will not need to depend on what parameter list the program's `main` function has.

The implementation is also allowed to define additional valid parameter lists for the `main` function (The POSIX spec specifies a `char **env` parameter for the environment variables, for example). It would not be clear when an overload of `main` is a "non-main function" or whether it's a "main function", thus an entry point. Presumably, you would want to get an error if you would declare more than one entry point, so such issues are important.

Comment: Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: @bdonlan: http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pdf for example (ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E))

Comment: Lazy me. I should've looked up in the Standard itself. +1.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're saying about POSIX? Are you saying it allows a third argument to main?  I looked at the specification for [exec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) and it mentions a special `extern char** environ` as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is declare two entry points to the program's execution. This is forbidden by the compiler since when you run the program the program will not know where to begin!

I also can't see any reason why you would want to do this in your application's design.

Comment: Well, one could imagine how such a system would work. The program would start by calling the unique `main()` of the appropriate form. So it would pick the one of the form `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Clearly this doesn't happen, but it's not too hard to imagine that it could, if it were desirable.

Answer (score -2):

As per me **global main function(main function outside all classes) cannot in overloaded in c++,** But if you write main function inside a class then it will compile fine however it will not be treated as program entry point
for example the following code will not compile file name mainoverloaderror.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int noofarg,char *values[])
{
    std::cout<<"hello "<<endl<<values[0]<<endl<<values[1]<<endl<<noofarg;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
 std::cout<<"hello main()";
    return 0;
}
```

compilation error :
mainoverloaderror.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mainoverloaderror.cpp:13: error: declaration of C function ‘int main()’ conflicts with
mainoverloaderror.cpp:7: error: previous declaration ‘int main(int, char**)’ here

Look at this code main function inside a class. Although it will not have multiple entry point but will compile fine:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class MainClass{

        int main1()
    {

        std::cout<<"hello main()"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int main(int noofarg,char *values[])
    {

        std::cout<<"hello "<<endl<<values[0]<<endl<<values[1]<<endl<<noofarg;
        return 0;
    }
    int main()
    {

     std::cout<<"hello main()";
        return 0;

    }
};

int main()
{

 std::cout<<"hello main()";
    return 0;

}
```

**so to conclude**: in c++ global main cannot be overloaded it will generate compile time error, in is because you cannot have multiple entry point for the same program as said above.